# Changing amount of questions based on what the user says in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, counter

I am trying to have a Python script that asks you how many URLs you want to input, then asks for that amount of URL. So if you say that you have 5 URLs, then it would ask you for a URL 5 times.

So it asks for URLs, you say you have X amount of URLs, so it asks for X amount of different URLs.

The only thing i can think of is the following.

```
while True:
    if amount > 1:
        url1 = input("Whats your first url? ")
        continue
    if amount > 2:
        url2 = input("Whats your second url? ")
        continue
```

Above is the only thing i can think of as, I'm relatively uninformed regarding coding and python as a language. If you have a better way of doing this, please let me know and tell me what libraries i need to either install or import, sorry if im asking alot but once again, i'm not the greatest at coding, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into what for-loops are. I would make a loop over a range(1,x), x being the amount of URLs your user has stated in the outset. Then you simply add each new URL to a list instead of its own variable. That should be a lot easier..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
urlnum = int(input("How many urls?"))
urllist = []

for e in range(urlnum):
    urllist.append(input("Type URL %s" % str(e+1)))
```

then to get a url, you would use `urllist[0]` to get the first one, `urllist[1]` to get the second, etc.

Comment: This is someone off topic but, how would i go about trying to check for the amount of items on said array? For example, one of my scripts that uses the URLs doesn't seem too work that well when it tries to get a URL that isn't there, so is there a way i can either save number of URLs to a file like I saved the URLs to a file using the "Pickle" library? Or can i find the amount of URLs on the array and then have a loop that saves the URLs as different variables and then use the URLs from that point? Or if none of this work, could you tell me what the most efficient way of doing this would be?

Comment: To find how many objects there are in a list, just use `len(urllist)`. You shouldn't need to save the objects in a list as different variables. Just use urllist[<the number of the url you want>] as the variable you want to use.

Comment: If you want to apply an operation to each of the urls, for example deleting spaces around them, you can loop over it like this: `urllist = [url.strip() for url in urllist]`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your ultimate goal is though.

Comment: I made a new question explaining my end goal better.